# Finding the location of data write using fwrite function in C

Tags: c

I want to write multiple structures to a single file. I used fwrite function and append mode. The writing process is done without any error. How can i read the specific structure. Which means if i want to read the third structure that i wrote to file, how can i do it. I used fseek function and try to find the third position and read it using fread. But it didn't worked. Please can anyone help me.

Comment: Didn't work how? what failed?

Comment: You cannot write a "struct" can you? You'll have to write it's data members or some serialised variant of the structure. You can read it back in the same way. Do you have some sample code or some errors which you encountered?

Comment: do you use a binary mode on a file?

Comment: Did you add b to a in your fopen instruction so that it handles binary data ?

Comment: Yes there is no syntax or other error. When i was fread, it reads always first structure. And when i was open that file using notepad( can identify) it always shows only first structure.

Comment: Then you obviously have problem with your fwrite call. Could you provide the code you use?

Comment: @Oleg Here my code:      
`person p1; /* Structure */     
FILE *test;     
test = fopen( "test", "ab" );     
fwrite( &p1, sizeof(person), 1, test);`

Comment: So you put one struct into the file. Obviosly you can reaf only one then. Or maybe I got you wrong? If you are not reopening rile for reading you should use "+" option like "ab+".

Comment: No no this is a function. So when it called it must save the structure to the specific file. What is + sign means? (The structure declaration is not in the function)

Comment: + means you will read from file as well. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fopen/

Comment: Then i must use + sign. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Since the data is stored as binary, you shouldn't use notepad to look at the data. You'll see garbage. You should use a binary file viewer (hexadecimal combined with text display).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FILE * pFile;
pFile = fopen ( "example.txt" , "rb" );
fseek ( pFile , sizeof(MyStruct)*2 , SEEK_SET );
MyStruct str;
fread(&str, sizeof(MyStruct), 1, pFile,)
```

Comment: Correct, but you could have made explicit that this code doesn't handle any error condition on fopen, fseek or fread for educational purpose.

Comment: So the problem was the missing + after ab in the fopen.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `fwrite()`, use `+a` tag